# Endpoint that returns all SQL rows between two timestamps in REST API written

Tags: mysql, rest, go

I have created a REST API for fetching records from a database in which every row is information about a past purchase in a grocery store.

In my main.go file I have declared a function that connects to my database and in turn creates a route in which all purchases can be fetched.

```
func HandleRequests() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")

    if len(port) == 0 {
        port = "8080"
    }
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "<link-to-my-MYSQL-database>")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.HandleFunc("/purchases", getAllPurchases).Methods("GET")

    http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router)
}
```

Here, my handler fetches all rows in the MYSQL schema and returns it as JSON.

```
func getAllPurchases(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    response.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
    var purchases Data

    result, err := db.Query("SELECT Timestamp,PurchaseID,CustomerID  from purchases ORDER BY Timestamp")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer result.Close()
    for result.Next() {
        var purchase Purchase
        err := result.Scan(&purchase.Timestamp, &purchase.PurchaseID, &purchase.CustomerID)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        purchases.Data = append(purchases.Data, purchase)
    }
    json.NewEncoder(response).Encode(purchases)
}
```

Here are the structs.

```
type Data struct {
    Data []Request `json:"data"`
}

type Purchase struct {
    Timestamp    string `json:"Timestamp"`
    PurchaseID   int `json:"PurchaseID"`
    CustomerID   int `json:"CustomerID"`
}
```

The Timestamp is formatted like this: `"Timestamp": "2021-01-11T16:25:52.499762+01:00",`

So this works well and all, the code is successfully able to return all rows in the MySQL table.

**My objective is to do the same but instead of fetching all purchases create an endpoint that returns all rows between two timestamps.**

Naturally, the SQL query would be something like this

```
SELECT * from Purchases WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2015-05-06T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2015-04-06T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS');
```

But I am puzzled as to how to craft the endpoint url. What would it be called? My assumption is something in the style of

> /purchases/{timestamp1}{timestamp2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There cannot be a single narrow precise answer.

As to designing endpoint, many approaches fit.
I'd say the approach you have proposed has a flaw as its unnatural to pass two timestamps without any delimiters between them.

If I were to design it, I would either go with

`/endpoint/{from_ts}/{untl_ts}`

(that is, have two path components),
or have the endpoint accept query parameters:

`/endpoint?from={from_ts}&to={to_ts}`

You also have to fix the format of the timestamps in the documentation of your API. Please consider making the timezone specification required or require all timestamps to be in UTC (better).  This will make your solution future-proof.

As to actually making a query to the DB engine, you *must* use prepared statements (never ever embed strings obtained from the user into a query to not be [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)).
Basically that amounts to using placeholders in the query text at the places a parameter should be used, then "preparing" that query to obtain a prepared statement which can then be executed and executing allows passing actual parameters for the database driver to send them for the positional parameters of the query. You may start [here](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_Stmt).

Also be sure to validate the timestamps before attempting to use them, and fail the request with the 400 HTTP status code if any of them is not valid.
Validation is a byproduct of parsing a string containing a timestamp to `time.Time`, so I'd just use that.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed and elaborate answer! I have two questions. With time stamp validation, you mean that I should enforce some sort of check that filters out timestamps that are invalid, e.g. a date that has not yet occured? And why are UTC timestamps more future proof?

Comment: 1) No, you merely should reject syntactically incorrect timestamps (those which do not parse according to the selected format to use for timestamps). Say, if you elect to stick to `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss` then `2021-01-15T23:59.59` would parse OK but `foobar` won't and `2021-15-01T59:23:23` won't as well). 2) Novice devs (please take no offence just in case) tend to take for granted it's OK to assume all timestams are in the local time zone (local to the place that dev lives/works)…

Comment: ….This only works OK until access to your app crosses at least a single timezone (which can even occur in mid-sized european countries, let alone countries like USA or Russia (the latter spans full 8 time zones, for instance). And once you start dealing with timezones it sort-of naturally occurs that mandating all timestamps must be in UTC makes life only slightly harder—basically for debugging endpoints with things like `curl` or Postman—because when you do requests from another program, converting any timestamp to UTC is a no-brainer.

Comment: …and using UTC timestamps removes any questions regarding comparisons of what event happens after what in a geographically distributed system.